# what does the leading byte represent for the initial point G?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Per [SEC 2](http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf#page=18), the base point $G$ for `secp192r1` is as follows:

```
G = 04 188DA80E B03090F6 7CBF20EB 43A18800 F4FF0AFD 82FF1012
07192B95 FFC8DA78 631011ED 6B24CDD5 73F977A1 1E794811
```

According to [this JavaScript ECDH Key Exchange Demo](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/ecdh.html), when you click the `secp192r1` button, the $(x, y)$ coordinates for $G$ are as follows:

- `x = 602046282375688656758213480587526111916698976636884684818`
- `y = 174050332293622031404857552280219410364023488927386650641`

$x$ is equal to what you'd get if you converted `188DA80E B03090F6 7CBF20EB 43A18800 F4FF0AFD 82FF1012` from hex to decimal. Same thing for `07192B95 FFC8DA78 631011ED 6B24CDD5 73F977A1 1E794811`.

But what does the `04` at the beginning mean?

Comment: Since you found SEC2, this is in SEC1 (2.3.3-4) at the same place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But what does the `04` at the beginning mean?

It means 'this elliptic curve point is specified in uncompressed format', that is, the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are given explicitly.

The other alternatives are :

- `02`, which means 'this is a compressed point, where we give the $x$ coordinate explicitly; of the two possible $y$ coordinates that are compatible with that $x$ coordinate, select the one with the 0 lsbit.
- `03`, which is the same, except you select the $y$ coordinate with a 1 lsbit.

The compressed formats are about half as long (saving space), but requires more computation (a modular square root) to use if you perform an operation that requires the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: It looks like for binary curves that it's not quite as simple as "is the square root odd or even". I understand that on an elliptic curve any x axis coordinate that intersects with the curve will do so at two points. It stands to reason that one point would be "higher" (possessing of a larger y) than the other. Maybe "02" and "03" are more generally understood as "high point" and "low point"?

Comment: @neubert: yes, for a binary curve, it becomes "find the two solutions to this quadratic equation".  I've never worked with compressed points to binary curves, and I'm not certain which they assign the lables `02` and `03` to.